# "NAs introduced by coercion" in seqecreate

Tags: r, traminer

I am using `seqecreate` to specify an event sequence object using `TraMineR`.

The dataset has 1271 rows and 4 columns, an id, timestamp (timed), and 2 event variables (one numeric and one string).  Most of the data have only 1 event per id.  I've done other analyses with these data in SAS without issues.  When I run `seqecreate` the procedure stops at id 425 with an error message:

```
> etv.ev <- seqecreate(id=etvev$id, timestamp=etvev$timed, event=etvev$event2, use.labels=FALSE)

Warning message:

In seqecreate.internal(data = data, id = id, timestamp = timestamp,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

The offending data in this part of the dataframe look ok (row 535 is the last before the error):

```
row     id       event2 timed event1
534 2144155702   xETV     0      1
535 2149998801   xETV     0      1
536 2150098301   xETV     0      1
537 2150098301   ETV2    27      2
538 2152463101   xETV     0      1
```

This error occurs with both event variables.  I'd like to understand the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Playing around with your data, I found the problem is with the id column. The error occurs when the id exceeds some value. This is a bug in `seqecreate`.

A workaround is to pass your ids as a factor:

```
seqecreate(id=factor(etvev$id), timestamp=etvev$timed, event=etvev$event2)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And a perfect example of how posting your data really, really helps get good answers!